# R character variables in function

Tags: r, function

I’ve worked with SAS and SQL previously I’m trying to get into R via a course. I’ve been set the following task by my tutor:

“Using the Iris dataset, write an R function that takes as its arguments an Iris species and attribute name and returns the minimum and maximum values of the attribute for that species.”

Which sounded straightforward at first, but I’ve come unstuck trying to make the function. The below is as far as I've gotten

```
 #write the function
question_2 <- function(x, y, data){
new_table <- subset(data, Species==x)
themin <-min(new_table$y)
themax <-max(new_table$y)
return(themin)
return(themax)}
#test the function - Species , Attribute, Data
question_2("setosa",Sepal.Width, iris)
```

I assumed I needed quotes around the species when running the function, but I get an error that there were "no non-missing arguments to min/max", which I'm guessing means my attempt at making 'new_table' has brought back zero observations.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

edit: thanks all for the swift and insightful responses. i'll take that reading on board. thanks again!

Comment: The code after the first `return(...)` is not reached. Do `return(c(mi=themin, ma=themax))` Further you have to do `new_table[, y]` and call `question_2("setosa", "Sepal.Width", iris)`

Comment: You might want to read The Non-standard evaluation part of Hadley wickham's 'advanced R': http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, your teacher didn't give you the easiest thing to do in R. You were almost right. You can't return twice in a function.

```
question_2 <- function(x, y, data){
new_table <- subset(data, Species==x)
themin <-min(new_table[[y]])
themax <-max(new_table[[y]])
return(list(themin, themax))}

question_2("setosa","Sepal.Width", iris)
```

Comment: One proposed edit to your output is: `return(c(themin, themax))`. Since `themin` and `themax` are of the same type, avoiding Sexpr's lets R concatenate output. This is good when functions are used in loops like `sapply`.. Just programming practice that benefits me in day-to-day R'ing.

Answer (score 1):

`df$colname` cannot be used with a variable to the right of `$`, because it will search for the column named `"colname"` (`"y"` in your case) rather than the character the variable `colname` (if it even exists) represents.

The syntax `df[["colname"]]` is useful in this case because it allows for character input (which may also be a variable representing a character). This holds for both object types `list` and `data.frame`. In fact, a `data.frame` can be seen as a list of vectors.

---

**Example**

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = 5:7, col2 = letters[1:3])

a <- "col1"

# $ vs [[
df$col1       # works because "col1" is a column of df
df$a          # does not work because "a" is not a column of df

df[["col1"]]  # works because "col1" is a column of df  
df[[a]]       # works because "col1" is a column of df

# dataframes can be seen as list of vectors
ls <- list(col1 = 5:7, col2 = letters[1:3])
ls$col1  # works
ls[[a]]  # works
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that `Sepal.Width` seems to be some object in the workspace. Otherwise R would yell at you `Object "Sepal.Width" not found.`. Whatever `Sepal.Width` (the object) is, it is probably not a character string with the value `"Sepal.Width"`. But even if it were, R would not know how to use the `$` operator to get that named column from `new_table`, not without some needlessly advanced programming. @Flo.P's suggestion of using `[[` is a good one.

You must pass `y` as `"Sepal.Width"`.

Another approach: you can take advantage of `subset` by writing this:

```
question_2 <- function(x, y, data){
newy <- subset(data, subset=Species==x, select=y)
themin <-min(newy)
themax <-max(newy)
return(c(themin, themax))
```

}

```
question_2("setosa","Sepal.Width", iris)
```